# How to prevent print() lift up input text while user is typing

Tags: python, command-line-interface

Basically, I have a async worker doing stuff, but I can caught an user command line any time.

The problem is just visual, when the user is typing and the code prints something, the text the user was typing is lifted up together with the printed text. How to make the last line "isolated" from console?

this is an exemple code:

```
import queue
import  threading
import time
import heapq

def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        if item is None:
            break
        do_work(item)
        #q.task_done()
        time.sleep(2)
        q.put(item)



def do_work(item):
    print(item,end = '')
    print(time.time(), end = '')


q = queue.PriorityQueue()
num_worker_threads = 1
threads = []
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)


fruits = [(1,"apple"), (2,"banana"), (3,"cherry")]
for x in fruits:
  q.put(x)

gameFinished = 0
# block until all tasks are done
#q.join()

while not gameFinished:
    q.put((-1,input()))

# stop workers
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
    q.put(None)
for t in threads:
    t.join()


input("Press enter to exit ;)")
```

Comment: Nice, complete example, but I have to ask why the background process needs to print anything at all?

Comment: `print()`is all but useless in real applications, it's expensive and clutters things. It's good for debugging, but otherwise you'd just use `logging` etc. for messages.

Comment: @roganjosh I'm planning a experimental bot and need the worker tell me what's happening. Let me try logging, maybe it fits

Comment: I wouldn't say it's super-easy to set up, logging can be a little tricky, but `print` won't cut it in any kind of serious application.

Comment: @roganjosh got the same problem with logging